# Python Persistance-List

Tags: python, list

Multiplying the digits of an integer and continuing the process gives the surprising result that the sequence of products always arrives at a single-digit number. For example:
715  35  15  5 88  64  24  8 27  14  4
The number of products necessary to reach the single-digit number is called the persistence number of
that integer. Thus 715 and 88 have a persistence number of 3, while 27 has persistence 2.
Make a program to find the only two-digit number with persistence greater than 3? 
this is the problem.

```
for i in range(10,100):
    for l in range(i):
        numbers = list(str(l))
        num = int(numbers[0]) * int(numbers[1])
```

this is what i have. please help

Answer (score 0):

Everyone thinks this is a bad question, so I feel bad for answering and helping you cheat :(
but it was fun to do! :) and solving stuff is a sign you're smart, heh, and not really trying is a sign of the opposite.

```
def newn(n):
    numbers = [int(c) for c in str(n)]
    new = 1
    for i in numbers:
        new *= i
    digits = len(str(new))
    return new, digits

for n in xrange(99,9,-1):
    if persistence > 3:
        print 'persistence %i, number %i' % (persistence, n + 1)
        break

    digits, persistence = 2, 0
    while digits != 1:
        persistence += 1
        n, digits = newn(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is `77`, which goes to `49`, which goes to `36`, which goes to `18` which goes to `8`.

```
def multiply_digits(x):
    total = 1
    for digit in str(x):
        total *= int(digit)
    return total

for value in range(11, 100):
    new_value = multiply_digits(value)
    persistance = 1
    while new_value >= 10:
        new_value = multiply_digits(new_value)
        persistance += 1
        if persistance > 3:
            print value
```